# Optimizing mySQL query with almost identical subquery

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to optimize the following query?

```
SELECT s1.* FROM
(SELECT s.* 
FROM answer a, answer_item ai, sessions s
WHERE s.session_state='FINISHED' AND a.sessionId=s.id AND ai.answer=a.id
AND a.question=1001 AND ai.question_variant_id=1103) s1, 
(SELECT s.* 
FROM answer a, answer_item ai, sessions s
WHERE s.session_state='FINISHED' AND a.sessionId=s.id AND ai.answer=a.id
AND a.question=1003 AND ai.question_variant_id=1301) s2
WHERE s1.id=s2.id
```

Everything seems to be the same except these parts:

1. `a.question=1001 AND ai.question_variant_id=1103`
2. `a.question=1003 AND ai.question_variant_id=1301`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be looking for sessions (or whatever) who answered both questions.  I think the following may get you the rows that you want.  However, you may have to do more work to get the right columns:

```
  SELECT s.* 
  FROM answer a JOIN
       answer_item ai
       ON ai.answer = a.id JOIN
       sessions s
       ON a.sessionId = s.id
  WHERE s.session_state = 'FINISHED' AND
        (a.question = 1001 AND ai.question_variant_id = 1103 OR
         a.question = 1003 AND ai.question_variant_id = 1101
        )
  GROUP BY s.id
  HAVING SUM(a.question = 1001 AND ai.question_variant_id = 1103) > 0 AND
         SUM(a.question = 1003 AND ai.question_variant_id = 1101) > 0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT s.* 
FROM answer a
JOIN answer_item ai ON ai.answer=a.id
JOIN sessions s ON a.sessionId=s.id
WHERE s.session_state='FINISHED'
AND 
(
      a.question=1001 AND ai.question_variant_id=1103
   OR a.question=1003 AND ai.question_variant_id=1301
)
```

Comment: Hi, @juergen d! Thank you for the answer! Unfortunately, the optimized query dataset differs. It contains 84 rows, though the original query dataset contains just 30.

Answer (score 1):

Check below optimized query.

```
SELECT  s.* FROM  FROM answer a, answer_item ai, sessions s
WHERE s.session_state='FINISHED' AND a.sessionId=s.id AND ai.answer=a.id
AND ( 
   (a.question=1001 AND ai.question_variant_id=1103)
   OR 
   (a.question=1003 AND ai.question_variant_id=1301)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one (`JOIN` tables `answer` and `answer_item` two times for this):

```
SELECT s.* 
FROM answer a
JOIN answer_item ai ON ai.answer=a.id
JOIN sessions s ON a.sessionId=s.id
JOIN answer a2 ON s.id=a2.sessionId
JOIN answer_item ai2 ON ai2.answer=a2.id
WHERE s.session_state='FINISHED'
AND ( (a.question=1001 AND ai.question_variant_id=1103)
AND (a2.question=1003 AND ai2.question_variant_id=1301) )
```

Comment: Hi, @Kleskowy! Thank you for the answer! If replace 'OR' with 'AND' in the condition it works.